# Photos not visible in gallery

Tags: gallery

I'm using Samsung S Duos 7582. My phone was hanged and i restarted it , after that the pictures in my device storage and SD card is not visible in Gallery. And not able to select the mp3 songs as my ring tone, I've restarted the mobile device many times. But no change , kindly suggest.

Comment: Those files probably got corrupted. Where did you save them to? If on SD card: Use a file manager (or a card reader with your PC) and watch out for a folder called `LOST.DIR`. Does it exist, and are there any files in (usually with "cryptic names")?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your SD Card has been corrupted.

Here i will suggest check with another device so it will be clear that what's the main problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your memory card got corrupted. 
If it is not so then copy contents to your computer and then format the memory card with your phone...
Again copy contents from your computer to card ..
Now it should work...

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late to answer this now but I think someone else will find this helpful.

Go to file manager you'll find a folder named `DCIM` change its name to `DCIM0` or something like that. Then create a new folder named `DCIM`. Reboot. It should be alright after this. You can move the pictures and videos in `DCIM0` back to `DCIM` after this if you want.